# Building and getting a form of objects that have multiple properties

Tags: python, html, django

I'm building a form dynamically in a web app where I'm using `product_id` to keep track which product I'm reading and then `product_<id>_property` to grab the value of it. Then in my view I end up with this:

```
for product_id in request.POST.getlist('product_id'):
    ProductPlacement.objects.create(
        product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id),
        board = board,
        x = request.POST.get('product_{0}_x'.format(product_id)),
        y = request.POST.get('product_{0}_y'.format(product_id)),
        width = request.POST.get('product_{0}_width'.format(product_id)),
        height = request.POST.get('product_{0}_height'.format(product_id)),
        rotation = request.POST.get('product_{0}_rotation'.format(product_id)),
        z = 0
    )
```

It's not very pretty, is there a nicer more readable way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite ok and I have no idea how to improve this particular piece.

You have used several identical forms and processed it manually. Django have [formsets](http://django.me/formsets) for this purpose. Why don't you use them?

Then I don't see validation in your code. What happens when `product_0_width` contains not-numeric or empty value? Formsets would solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If your list of attributes varies, the below might be a bit more future-proof:

```
for product_id in request.POST.getlist('product_id'):
    attribs = { 'product' : Product.objects.get(id=product_id),
                'board' = board,
                'z' = 0
              }
    for attrib in [ 'x', 'y', 'width', 'height', 'rotation' ]:
        attribs[attrib] = request.POST.get('product_{0}_{1}'.format(product_id, attrib))
    ProductPlacement.objects.create(**attribs)
}
```

but overall what you've got is quite legible and easily understandable, if a bit repetitive.  Note that what @San4ez said is true: there's no validation in the above, so it may need to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might consider this to be somewhat more readable?

```
# for Python 3.x
class Getter:

    def __init__(self, request, product_id):
        self.get = request.POST.get
        self.pid = product_id

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.get('product_{}_{}'.format(self.pid, name))

for product_id in request.POST.getlist('product_id'):
    get = Getter(request, product_id)
    ProductPlacement.objects.create(
        product=Products.objects.get(id=product_id),
        board=board,
        x=get.x,
        y=get.y,
        width=get.width,
        height=get.height,
        rotation=get.rotation,
        z=0
    )
```

If you like it, more of your code might be structured similarly.